# subsets question from leetcode( question 78)

Tags: python

```
def solution(arr):
    sol=[[]]
    temp=[[]]
    for num in arr:
        for i in range(len(temp)):
            temp[i].append(num)
            sol.append(temp[i])          
        temp=sol.copy()
    return sol
```

This is my code. I was trying to add the new subsets from temp array to the solution array. but the command sol.append(temp[i]) isnt working as it should.instead of appending temp[i], the original values in sol array are getting changed. for array [1], the output is correct, but for array>len 1, it is showing weird values..

can someone help me pleasee..!

Comment: Could you tell us the problem to solve ? Also share example input with the actual output and the expected one ?

Comment: Given an integer array nums of unique elements, return all possible subsets (the power set).

The solution set must not contain duplicate subsets. Return the solution in any order.

 

Example 1:

Input: nums = [1,2,3]
Output: [[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]
Example 2:

Input: nums = [0]
Output: [[],[0]]
 

Constraints:

1 <= nums.length <= 10
-10 <= nums[i] <= 10
All the numbers of nums are unique  @azro

Comment: [edit] the post, don't add important information in comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indentation needs some fixing and clean some unnecessary code.

```
def solution(arr):
    sol = [[]]
    for num in arr:
        for i in range(len(sol)):
            temp = list(sol[i])
            temp.append(num)
            sol.append(temp)
    return sol
```